# Using the java timer

Tags: java, android, timer

Until now I have been using the `Timer` that's in `javax.swing.timer` - all I had to do was to choose the speed and have a method with a specific name that executes what I want the timer to do every time.

I have now started programming an Android application recently and I have faced a couple of problems...

1. It wouldn't let me use or import `javax.swing.timer`
2. I tried using `java.util.timer` but I couldnt figure out how it works

All I want my timer for is so I can display my logo for 3 seconds and then proceed to the main menu - even if there is an easier solution for this, I'd still like to know how to use the timer

For the person who told me to try using a thread - here is my code - it doesnt paint the first screen at all, it just stays blank for 3 seconds then moves on to the next line of code...

```
public class logo extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        try {
            setContentView(R.layout.logoview);
            Thread.sleep(3000); 
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void startup (View view){
        Intent intent0 = new Intent (this,ExpiramantingActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent0);}
    }
}
```

Comment: what could you not use with the java.util.timer ? its pretty straightforward in your case . can you provide some code and any error ?

Comment: i dont understand how it works, what are timertasks? i tried something like this:

Timer timer1 =new timer();
     timer1.schedule(startup(), 1000)
    
 
    public void startup (View view){
     
     
      Intent intent0 = new Intent (this,ExpiramantingActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent0);}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in onCreate() function of your SplashActivity class, schedule a handler to display your main menu activity after 3 seconds. this should be done after setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this,
                            YourMainMenuActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
            }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a Thread? I think it's the simplest way to do what you want:

Where you display your logo:

```
try {
    //show your logo here
    Thread.sleep(3000); //3 seconds
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Surrounding the code in a try/catch block is very important, because of the posibility of an Exception.

Comment: Maybe you can explain why? I'm begginer too, so be forgiving :)

Comment: :) because , java.util.timer is a whole facility dedicated to timing your tasks. i suggest you read docs and check some examples . Thread sleep is so raw and not managed for this kind of usage. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: what is the answer then? what exactly does a thread do? simply delays the next line of code in the amount of time specified?

Comment: well isnt that exactly what i wanted? - see the edit i made to my Question -why doesnt it work?

Comment: is my last solution was helpful?

Comment: I would also point out that if you actually caught a `InterruptedException` that in all likely hood you do *not* want to simply catch print the trace, but also to propagate the interrupt via `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you are trying to do is similar to the exhibition Splash Screen. If so, please check this [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html).

Comment: does this work with android apps? where should the splash screen go?

Comment: I am not familiar with the android environment, but check this link: http://www.droidnova.com/how-to-create-a-splash-screen,561.html

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
// logo
Thread timer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }; 
        };
        timer.start();

//next code
```